# upload file to msteams sharepoint channel using webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to upload a text file to msteams sharepoint.

I have the webhook url of the channel

Is there a rest api for uploading the file using the webhook as the authenticator

Comment: The Files tab in channel is linked to SharePoint site default folder. Please take a look at Upload Files(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). This API restricted to file size to 4MB. if you want to upload greater than 4MB please take a look at Upload larger files(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: I want to upload files smaller than 4MB, and all I have is a msteams channel webhook URL. How do I use this webhook url to upload files to the specific sharepoint ?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I want to upload files smaller than 4MB, and all I have is a msteams channel webhook URL. How do I use this webhook url to upload files to the specific sharepoint ?

Comment: Using Graph API its possible, but using webhook it doesn't seem to be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

For more visibility, adding answer from comment section:

Using Graph API its possible, but using Webhook it doesn't seem to be feasible.